# ASP.NET Start Page loads always the Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

Independently of what i do my web app Start Page it's always the MasterPage. I have a Masterpage that most of the pages inherit, but i also have a "Entrada.aspx" to work as a landing page, that doesn't inherit the Masterpage. I want that "Entrada.aspx" is the default page but i can't set it be any means.

This is the header:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Entrada.aspx.cs" Inherits="webapp.Entrada" %>
```

I've set Entrada.aspx as the start page in the webapp Visual Web Properties -> Start Action

```
Specific Page: Entrada.aspx
```

I've also set it in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="Entrada.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

And doesn't work either.

I've already set it in Visual Web Context menu "Set as Start Page" and it doesn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't go to Entrada.aspx in debug mode or after publish?

Comment: This may seem trivial, but have you tried changing your `<clear/>` statement to contain a space before the closing bracket, e.g. `<clear />`.

Comment: @nima If i run debug it goes to http://localhost:59852/Entrada.aspx, but if i go to http://localhost:59852/ directly from browser it loads the MasterPage first

Comment: @Mendicant I've done it. Didn't help Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using Visual Studio Development Server and you don't need to go to localhost:59852 for debugging. Just let the address be localhost:59852/Entrada.aspx.
But in your production server where your using IIS it will work.

Comment: I was going to localhost:59852, to test if when sending to my webserver if it redirects to Entrada.aspx when going to domain.com/ . But it doesnt behave the same way in VS Development Server. I've sent it to webserver and it actually works as expected. Thanks!